# CSS styles not picked up when device orientation change

Tags: css

I have the following CSS to style a layout when the user is in landscape mode on their device. It works when you load the page in landscape mode but when loading it in portrait mode and you change the orientation. the portrait layout remains on landscape.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 

        .qv-overlay-container{
            top:0px;
        }
.........

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do u have this problem on any specific device?

Comment: Can you create code snippet here with HTML and CSS so that it can be debugged in more detail...

Comment: I made a test page and it worked on my Moto android device and, iPhone simiulator mode on PC chrome when changing orientation. Your problem must be somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px),
(orientation : landscape) {...}
```

---

Explanation

The 'and' keyword is used here combines multiple media features together, as well as combines media features with media types.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {...}
```

> The above media query will only apply if the media type is screen, the
>   viewport is width is between 320px to 667px, and the display is in
>   landscape.

---

Comma-separated lists behave like the logical operator or when used in media queries. When using a comma-separated list of media queries, if any of the media queries returns true, the styles or style sheets get applied. Each media query in a comma-separated list is treated as an individual query, and any operator applied to one media query does not affect the others. This means the comma-separated media queries can target different media features, types, and states.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px),
(orientation : landscape) {...}
```

> Above, if screen device with a viewport width is between 320px to
>   667px, the media statement would return true because the first part,
>   interperated as @media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 667px) would apply to
>   device and therefore return true, despite the fact that my screen
>   device would fail the landscape orientation check in the second media
>   query. Likewise, if device is in landscape with a viewport width of
>   800px, while the first media query would fail due to the viewport
>   width, the second media query would succeed and thus the media
>   statement would return true.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)